# Adding Job Array elements in Slurm after submission

Tags: bash, slurm

I'm trying to use a Slurm-operated cluster to run LS-Dyna (a finite-element simulation program **with a limited number of licenses available on my cluster**). I am trying to write my batch scripts so that I do not waste processing time due to this license limit (as well as to improve legibility when running 'squeue' commands) by using job arrays -but I'm having trouble making that work.

I want to run identical Bash scripts in a variety of FEM meshes, each of which I have organized into different subfolders.

Given this folder structure on my cluster...

```
cluster root
|
...
|
|-+ my scratch space's root
  |
  |-+ this project
    |
    |--+ lat_-5mm
    |  |- runCurrentLine.bash
    |  |- other files
    |
    |--+ lat_-4.75mm
    |  |- runCurrentLine.bash
    |  |- other files
    |
    |--+ lat_-4.5mm
    |  |- runCurrentLine.bash
    |  |- other files
    |
   ...
    |
    |--+ lat_5mm
    |  |- runCurrentLine.bash
    |  |- other files
    |
    |
    |-sendDynaRuns.bash
    |-other dependencies
```

...I'm trying to submit "runCurrentLine.bash" in each folder by running the following script in my login node.

```
#!/bin/bash
iter=0
for foldernow in */; do

# change to subdirectory for current line iteration
    cd "./${foldernow}";

# make Slurm and user happy
    echo "sending LS Dyna simulation for ${pos}mm line..."
    sleep 1

# first line only: send batch, and get job ID
    if [ "${iter}" == 0 ];then

# send the batch...
        jobID=$(sbatch -J "Dyna" --array="${iter}"%15 runCurrentLine.bash)

# ...ensure that Slurm's output shows on console (which includes the job ID)...
        echo "${jobID}"

# ...and extract the job ID and save as a variable
        jobID=$(echo "${jobID}" | grep -Eo '[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?')

# subsequent lines: add current line to job array
    else
        scontrol update --jobid="${jobID}" --array="${iter}"%15 runCurrentLine.bash
    fi

# prepare to move onto next position
    iter=$((iter+1))
    cd ../
done
```

This setup properly sends the batch job for the first line, at -0.25mm*. However, for the second line onwards, it doesn't seem to do the same thing... This is what I end up getting on my console:

*: I intended the "lat_xmm" folders to be numerically ordered, but Unix doesn't seem to recognize that

```
$ ./sendDynaRuns.bash
sending LS Dyna simulation for -0.25mm line...
Submitted batch job 1081040
sending LS Dyna simulation for 0.25mm line...
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid job id specified
sending LS Dyna simulation for -0.5mm line...
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid job id specified
```

I know that runCurrentLine.bash runs just fine if I manually send it as a batch (and it runs to completion within the time limit I specified in-file, mainly since it doesn't have to compete with other lines for open licenses). What should I do to be able to get my code to work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are sending job arrays, you must send all the array in a single submission. You cannot add jobs to an existing array. If you need to start the jobs independently, they you should use regular jobs (but then you lose the ability to control how many jobs in parallel are running), but you would need to ahve the licenses as accountable resources to be able to ask for them and have SLURM take care of them.

Comment: I see you trying to send the same script several times, just changing the array ID and the folder. You should avoid the folder change and perform that inside your script, deciding which is the proper folder from the job array ID. Then, the command you are looking for is a lot easier than all that mess: `sbatch -J "Dyna" --array="0-${nFolders}"%15 runCurrentLine.bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As state by @Poshi, you cannot add jobs to an existing array.

I would create a submission script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --array=1-<nb of folders>%15
# ALL OTHER SLURM SBATCH DIRECTIVES HERE

folders=(lat_*)
foldernow=${folders[$SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID]}

cd $foldernow && ./runCurrentLine.bash
```

The only drawback is that you need setup explicitly the number of jobs the array based on the number of folders.